# How to get the blob list of storage accounts with Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Microsoft Azure CLI and I could not find a way to list the blob object of a storage account.

I have the list displayed in Azure Web portal but I don't find any away to do it with the `az storage` command.

I've tried `az storage blob list` but it required a container name which I don't know how to find it (with az cli).

Do someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update: fetch the account key in cli:

Please try the code below, which can list all the blobs in all the containers of your storage account.

Note that there are no whitespaces aroud "=".

```
 # list storage account names
 az storage account list --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)"

 # update with your storage account name
 storage_account_name="your_storage_account_name"

 key="$(az storage account keys list -n ${storage_account_name} --query "[0].{value:value}" --output tsv)"
    
 containers="$(az storage container list --account-name ${storage_account_name} --account-key $key --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)"
    
 for c in $containers
 do
   echo "==== Blobs in Container $c ===="
   az storage blob list --container-name $c \
      --account-name ${storage_account_name} \
      --account-key $key \
      --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv
 done
```

Test results as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how I get my storage account key in my program ? 
When I want to list the key I have the following error. However,

Comment: @skidrow, why not get the key directly from the azure portal? and which error are your getting?

Comment: @skidrow, I updated the code, which get storage account key in cli code. And works fine at my side.

Comment: I got the following error when I want to list my account storage key with `az cli`:
`The client 'XXX@XXX.onmicrosoft.com' with object id '091bb6b2-XXX-46da-ac31-f350XXXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope ...`.
I understand I have no permission to do so but within the web portal, my user account is able to list the blob object of any storage account (All resources => 
<storage_account_name> => Objets blob).
Is this no possible with `az cli` to get this list (without the account storage key) ?

Comment: @skidrow, yes, without key, it's impossible :(.

Comment: `containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string '...')` generates this error: `is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. Any help?

Comment: @FrancoScarpa, can you please raise an new issue with more details, and then post the link here?

Comment: @IvanYang here or on GitHub?

Comment: @FrancoScarpa, here stackoverflow:)

Comment: @IvanYang: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449605/error-using-the-azurecli-task-in-pipeline

Comment: Instead of account key you can use `--auth-mode login` i.e. `az storage container list --auth-mode login --account-name youraccountname`. But you need to set appropriate role to your user first.

Comment: @IvanGlasenberg impossible without the account key? No, how about `az login` first.

Answer (score 3):

[Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-list) to get list of containers in a storage account on basis of storage ACCOUNT_NAME and ACCESS_KEY:

```
az storage container list --account-key ACCESS_KEY --account-name ACCOUNT_NAME
```

On basis of Container names received in its response, you can use `az storage blob list` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list) to get the list of objects within that container.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the solution can be divided in 3 part

1. Get the list of storage accounts and copy the "desired" account name from output

> az storage account list --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv

2. Then get "first key" of "desired" account and copy the string (dont copy double quotes :) )

> az storage account keys list --account-name WHATEVER_ACCOUNTNAME --query "[0].value"

3- Finally get the list of containers of your desired account (catch is here that "key" should be correctly copied from the output of second command)

> az storage container list --account-name WHATEVER_ACCOUNTNAME --account-key  YOUR-VERY-VERY-LONG-KEY --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv

Note-  Don't forget to login into azure account first of all  :).

> az login

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. I could see the containers in the portal but nothing made sense in any of the azure cli examples because I needed an account key.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple script to list all your blob containers. As a bonus, list all your file shares too !

```
# List all the storage accounts under a subscription


 for actname in $( az storage account list --query "[].name" --output tsv );  
 do   

# Get the storage key

    key1=`az storage account keys list --account-name $actname --query "[0].value" --output tsv 2>/dev/zero` 

# Exclude the listing when you do not have permission to look into the storage account - like databricks managed storage for example

    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
       continue 
    fi
 
 
    echo -e "\n === Here are the storage containers for your storage account $actname === \n"

# List of containers and file shares for the account

    az storage container list --account-name  $actname --account-key $key1  --query "[].name" --output tsv

    echo -e "\n --- Here are the storage file shares for your storage account $actname ---\n"


    az storage share list --account-name  $actname --account-key $key1 --query "[].name" --output tsv
    
 done
```