# Error using the AzureCLI task in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My Azure pipeline makes use of the **Azure CLI** task

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '...'
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string '...')
```

The task fails with this error:

```
The term 'containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string '...')' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1582829158619_inlinescript.ps1:1 char:1
+ containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string 'DefaultEn ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (containers=$(az sto\u2026ame}" --output tsv):String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

##[error]Script failed with error: Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe' failed with exit code 1
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd" account clear"
Finishing: AzureCLI
```

I can't figure out why it happens.

Comment: I suspect you are using a windows agent, not a linux one

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Windows agent.

Comment: well, in powershell it should be `$containers = $(xxx)`

Comment: @4c74356b41 you're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case the issue was due to a syntax mistake:

```
$containers=$(az storage container list --connection-string '...')
```

Comment: I take this opportunity to ask you this too, why do I get an error with this statement `for $c in $containers; do echo $c; done`?

Comment: thats not a valid powershell syntax, thats bash or something. in powershell its: `$containers.foreach{ $_ }`